# Navigation Drawer not working when startActivity is used in first case of selectItem

Tags: java, android, slidingdrawer

I have this problem with Google's Navigation Drawer where starting the activity specified in the first case (case 0) in my selectItem method breaks and returns to the previous activity.

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                            int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    switch(position) {
    case 0:
        // Placing any startActivity here will load the activity
        // but immediately return to the calling activity.
        parent.startActivity(new Intent(parent, Dashboard.class));                  
        break;
    case 1:
        parent.startActivity(new Intent(parent, Card.class));
        break;
    }
}
```

But if I put `mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);` or any other code, it'll work normally.

There are no errors reported when the called activity is closed and no exception is thrown. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you are calling finish() from the opening activity? What is parent?

Comment: No, I'm not calling finish() anywhere. The parent is Dashboard.class.

Comment: So you are trying to open another activity instance of your current activity?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'm trying to get to another activity using the navigation drawer.

Comment: If the parent is an instance of `Dashboard.class` which essentially should be the activity you are on (at best a subclass) and you are opening `Dashboard.class` then how would you know which one was the new vs the original? I guess what I'm trying to get at is are you sure it's doing what you are describing?

Comment: For `case 0`, you should be seeing `Dashboard` activity? Is this not what's happening?

Comment: Based on @J.Romero's comment, if you want to make sure that `startActivity(Intent)` did actually work: Show a `Toast` notification in your `onCreate(Bundle)` or if your Dashboard activity's launchMode is set to "singleTop", override `onNewIntent(Intent)` in Dashboard activity and show a `Toast`. If the Toast notification appears, `case 0` works.

Comment: No, let's say I want to get to Card activity from Dashboard activity. I am able to run through all of the lines of the Card activity onCreate normally, then it stops and goes back to the Dashboard activity.

Comment: You should post the code for `Card` activity.

Comment: It's basically a QR code generator. But the `Card` activity isn't the only activity that breaks the Navigation Drawer. ALL of them do (if I put them in `case 0:`, so posting it wouldn't help I'm afraid.

Comment: It is an `Activity` or `Fragment`. If this is fragment then use `startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Dashboard.class));`

Comment: So you want to launch a new Activity of the same class as the Activity you are on? If the new Activity is the same as the old, how can you be sure that it didn't work? Side note, why would you even want to do this anyway?

Comment: Why don't you use fragments instead of activities?

Comment: I don't use fragments because I don't know how to use them yet and currently don't have the time to implement it. But I do plan to at a later version. @AlexFu: No, I want to launch any activity (including the current one) defined in the menu of the drawer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing this and it will not resolve parent. Do you have it declared somewhere else ?

What class are you using this in both Activities and Fragments can use startActivity() without the need for parent.startActivity()

Can you post the complete class?

This works for ok for me.

```
private void selectItem(int position) {


    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        // goto home screen
        Log.d(TAG, "Showing Home");

        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class)); 
        break;

    case 1:
        // Show Editor
        Log.d(TAG, "Showing Editor");

        break;

    default:

        break;

    }

}
```

Comment: parent is simply `TheActivity parent = this' on `onCreate'. So it's the same as calling 'this.startActivity(...)'